# Channel Images in Wygwam, images dissapear

Tags: wygwam, channel-images, bug

So, the Channel Images input for Wygwam works fine. We can add an image to the wygwam field, save it, and voila. 
When we edit the entry though, click the wygwam to edit, the images disappear. Not just visually, but also in code.

All modules are up to date (Wygwam is 3.3.3 and Channel Images is 5.4.19). Expression engine is 2.9.3

Known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set 'Restrict allowed HTML' to no in my Wygwam fieldtype. That did it.